# How do I position a div with a colored background over a preceding image?

Tags: html, css

Stumped.

I have a basic card with an image and a text tag I want to float over the image.

The tag should have a background color behind the text and above the image.

The background of the text goes behind the image instead.

https://codepen.io/Mikeritteronline/pen/LwJYaR

---

#### html

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__image">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1024x768" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card__tag">
    <p>Image Tag</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### css

```
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  }
.card {
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  }
.card__tag p{
  background: blue;
  color: lime;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin-top: -3rem;
}
```

Comment: Google `absolute` and `fixed` positioning and `z-index` I guess these will do it. Also here's a helpful link: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-using-css.php

Comment: explain clearly your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its best if you position the div not the p like so:
(also generaly try to avoid positioning absolute if you do not have to)

```css
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  }
.card {
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  }

.card__tag{
  z-index: 1;
  position:relative;
  top: -3rem;
}
.card__tag p{
  background: blue;
  color: lime;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__image">
    <img src="//placehold.it/1024x768" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card__tag">
    <p>Image Tag</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `position` to achieve what you want.

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
}
.card__tag p {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
position: relative
```

to the p tag like

```
.card__tag p{
  background: blue;
  color: lime;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin-top: -3rem;

  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` to **.card** and `position:absolute` to **.card__tag**

Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.card {
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.card__tag p {
  background: blue;
  color: lime;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin-top: -3rem;
}

.card__tag {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__image">
    <img src="//placehold.it/1024x768" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card__tag">
    <p>Image Tag</p>
  </div>
</div>
```